# Truncate Meta Title and Meta Description in Magento2

Tags: magento2, seo, meta-title

turncate Meta title and meta description on pdp page how we can do that in which file we need to make changes .

Comment: what you mean by truncate?

Comment: i want turncate length

Comment: Meta Title
Case 1:

When the length of the Product Title is exceeding 60 Characters including the white spaces. Then Truncate it up to 60 Characters and use as “Meta Title”

Proposed Meta Title : “{Product Title}” (But Truncated up to 60 Characters Only)
Truncate the length of Product Title up to 60 Characters and use them for Meta Title of Product level pages.

Comment: i suggest to create custom script and than replace title and description. first get title and count word length and then truncate . one more thing why only in pdp page ?

Comment: for seo on ogogle

Answer (score 2):

In PDP, meta title and description is set via the product view helper class: `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View::preparePageMetadata()`.

So what you need to do is write a preference for this helper class as the method `preparePageMetadata()` is a private method. But, the best option would be doing the same through a plugin. To do this, you need to write an around plugin for the method `\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View:: prepareAndRender()` which is what actually call the private method `preparePageMetadata()`.

So I will just show you how you can achieve this through a plugin.

File: `app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View">
        <plugin
                name="NamespaceModuleAlterPDPMetaTags"
                type="Namespace\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Helper\Product\ViewPlugin" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Basically, this file will register our plugin dependency inside our module `Namespace_Module`.

File: `app/code/[Namespace]/[Module]/Plugin/Catalog/Helper/Product/ViewPlugin.php`

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\Module\Plugin\Catalog\Helper\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\View as ProductViewHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Registry;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils;


class ViewPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
     */
    private $coreRegistry;

    private $resultPage;

    private $string;

    public function __construct(Registry $coreRegistry, StringUtils $string)
    {
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->string = $string;
    }

    public function aroundPrepareAndRender(
        ProductViewHelper $productViewHelper,
        callable $proceed,
        Page $resultPage,
        $productId,
        $controller,
        $params = null
    ) {
        // collecting result page instance for future use
        $this->resultPage = $resultPage;

        // send the control to the original method
        $result = $proceed($resultPage, $productId, $controller, $params);

        // after meta title and description is generated, this will be executed

        // make sure the helper instance is correct
        if (!$result instanceof ProductViewHelper) {
            return $productViewHelper;
        }

        // collecting product information from the core registry
        $product = $this->coreRegistry->registry('product');

        // changing meta title and description as needed
        $this->alterMetaTitle($product);
        $this->alterMetaDescription($product);

       return $result;
    }

    /**
     * Changing meta title of PDP; Allowing only 60 characters
     * @param $product
     */
    private function alterMetaTitle($product)
    {
        $pageConfig = $this->resultPage->getConfig();
        $title = $product->getMetaTitle();

        if ($title) {
            $pageConfig->getTitle()->set($this->string->substr($title, 0, 60));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Changing meta description of PDP; Allowing only 60 characters
     * @param $product
     */
    private function alterMetaDescription($product)
    {
        $pageConfig = $this->resultPage->getConfig();
        $description = $product->getMetaDescription();

        if ($description) {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr($description, 0, 60));
        } else {
            $pageConfig->setDescription($this->string->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 60));
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, we wrote an around plugin for the method `prepareAndRender()`. Why we are relying on an around plugin is because we need the parameter `$resultPage` of the method in order to alter the meta title and description. Also, we need `$product` instance in order to retrieve the meta title and description. Product initialization is also happening inside `prepareAndRender()` method and hence will be obtained through the registry.

You can customize the methods `alterMetaTitle()` and `alterMetaDescription()` as per your need. Currently, it will enforce 60 character limit to both meta title and description.

I hope that gives you an idea.

**Note:** Module creation and usage of the plugin is out of scope concepts as per this question. If you need to know more details, please refer devdocs.